# Insert into table using data from JSON value in PostgresQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, migration

I am working on a sensitive migration. The scenario is as follows:

- I have a new table that I need to populate with data
- There is an existing table, which contains a column (type = json), which contains an array of objects such as:

```
[
 {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "custom-field-0",
    "label": "When is the deadline for a response?",
    "type": "Date",
    "options": "",
    "value": "2020-10-02",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "custom-field-1",
    "label": "What territory does this relate to?",
    "type": "Dropdown",
    "options": "UK, DE, SE, DK, BE, NL, IT, FR, ES, AT, CH, NO, US, SG, Other",
    "value": " DE",
    "index": 2
  }
]
```

I need to essentially map these values in this column to my new table. I have worked with JSON data in PostgresQL before, where I was dealing with a single object in the JSON, but never with arrays of objects and on such a large scale.

So just to summarise, how does someone iterate every row, and every object in an array, and insert that data into a new table?

**EDIT**

I have been experimenting with some functions, and I found one that seems promising `json_array_elements_text` or `json_array_elements`. As this allowed me to add multiple rows to the new table using this array of objects.

However, my issue is that I need to map certain values to the new table.

```
INSERT INTO form_field_value ("name", "label", "inputType", "options", "form" "workspace")
SELECT <<HERE IS WHERE I NEED TO EXTRACT VALUES FROM THE JSON ARRAY>>, task.form, task.workspace
FROM task;
```

**EDIT 2**

I have been playing around some more with the above functions, but reached a slight issue.

```
INSERT INTO form_field_value ("name", "label", "inputType", "options", "form" "workspace")
SELECT cf ->> 'name',
       (cf ->> 'label')
       ...
FROM jsonb_array_elements(task."customFields") AS t(cf);
```

My issue lies in the `FROM` clause, so `customFields` is the array of objects, but I also need to get the `form` and `workspace` attribute from this table too. Plus I a pretty sure that the FROM clause would not work anyway, as it probably will complain about the `task."customFields"` not being specified or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the select statement that uses `json_array_elements` and a lateral join in the `from` clause to flatten the data.

```sql
select j ->> 'name' as "name", j ->> 'label' as "label", 
  j ->> 'type' as "inputType", j ->> 'options' as "options", form, workspace
from task 
cross join lateral json_array_elements("customFields") as l(j);
```

The `from` clause can be less verbose

```sql
from task, json_array_elements("customFields") as l(j)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. This is a huge migration, and I still have a lot of data manipulation to work with. But this was a huge block in the road for me. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use json_to_recordset:

```
select * from json_to_recordset('
[
 {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "custom-field-0",
    "label": "When is the deadline for a response?",
    "type": "Date",
    "options": "",
    "value": "2020-10-02",
    "index": 1
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "custom-field-1",
    "label": "What territory does this relate to?",
    "type": "Dropdown",
    "options": "UK, DE, SE, DK, BE, NL, IT, FR, ES, AT, CH, NO, US, SG, Other",
    "value": " DE",
    "index": 2
  }
]
') as x(id int, name text,label text,type text,options text,value text,index int)
```

for insert record you can use an sql like this:

```
INSERT INTO form_field_value ("name", "label", "inputType", "options", "form" "workspace")
SELECT name, label, type, options, form, workspace
FROM 
  task, 
  json_to_record(task) AS 
 x (id int, name text,label text,type text,options text,value text,index int)
```